# Failing JavaScript onMouseOver event

Tags: javascript, php

I want to show `onmouseover` alert in PHP files but it fails. Please help me.

```
<?php
    $a = '<a href=# onMouseover=alert(';
    $a .= 'Für die Mitnahme von Sportgepäck &#40;Scuba/Diving/Golf Equipment&#41; bis'.
' 15 KG ist es empfehlenswert dieses vorab zu buchen, da sonst am Check-In '.
'Schalter die normalen Übergewichtsraten pro KG berechnet werden &#40;'.
'unabhängig von Ihrer Gepäckauswahl – die Auswahl des aufzugebenden Gepäcks '.
'beinhaltet nicht das Sportgepäck&#41';
    $a .= ')>LINK DESCRIPTION</a>';
    echo $a;
?>
```

Comment: Please describe *what* fails exactly.

Comment: As a side note, an `alert()` on mouse over is terribly annoying. Consider using a tooltip library like http://flowplayer.org/tools/tooltip/index.html .. more here: http://www.1stwebdesigner.com/css/stylish-jquery-tooltip-plugins-webdesign/

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php
    $a = '<a href=# onmouseover=alert("';
    $a .= 'Für die Mitnahme von Sportgepäck &#40;Scuba/Diving/Golf Equipment&#41; bis 15 KG ist es empfehlenswert dieses vorab zu buchen, da sonst am Check-In Schalter die normalen Übergewichtsraten pro KG berechnet werden &#40;unabhängig von Ihrer Gepäckauswahl – die Auswahl des aufzugebenden Gepäcks beinhaltet nicht das Sportgepäck&#41';
    $a .= '")>LINK DESCRIPTION</a>';
    echo $a;
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

There is no need for PHP here. Just write HTML:

```
<a href="#" onmouseover="alert('looong string...')">LINK DESCRIPTION</a>
```

It is much easier to read and to debug.

But an explanation for why your code does not work: You are messing up with quotes.

Answer (score 1):

This is the HTML you actually want :

```
<a href="#" onmouseover="alert('my text');">LINK DESCRIPTION</a>
```

Note the quotes around each attribute value and the single quote around the text of the alert. To obtain this in PHP, you can do it by escaping the quotes :

```
$a='<a href="#" onmouseover="alert(\'';
$a.='Für die [...] Sportgepäck&#41';
$a.= '\')">LINK DESCRIPTION</a>';
```

Answer (score 1):

Escape the string in the `alert`, like this:

```
<?php

    $a = '<a href=# onMouseover=alert(';
    $a .= '\'Für die Mitnahme von Sportgepäck &#40;Scuba/Diving/Golf Equipment&#41; bis 15 KG ist es empfehlenswert dieses vorab zu buchen, da sonst am Check-In Schalter die normalen Übergewichtsraten pro KG berechnet werden &#40;unabhängig von Ihrer Gepäckauswahl – die Auswahl des aufzugebenden Gepäcks beinhaltet nicht das Sportgepäck&#41\'';
    $a .= ')>LINK DESCRIPTION</a>';
    echo $a;
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of printing HTML code in PHP, escape PHP block:

```
<?php
// some PHP code and exit PHP block
?>

<a href="#" onmouseover="alert('Für die Mitnahme.....')">LINK DESCRIPTION</a>

<?php
// enter PHP block again
?>
```

However the problem was in missing apostrophes in `alert` function.

Was:

```
alert(some text)
```

should be:

```
alert('some text')
```

If you miss apostrophes, JavaScript treats your text as a variables.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php $a='Für die Mitnahme von Sportgepäck &#40;Scuba/Diving/Golf Equipment&#41; bis 15 KG ist es empfehlenswert dieses vorab zu buchen, da sonst am Check-In Schalter die normalen Übergewichtsraten pro KG berechnet werden &#40;unabhängig von Ihrer Gepäckauswahl – die Auswahl des aufzugebenden Gepäcks beinhaltet nicht das Sportgepäck&#41';
echo '<a href=\"#\" onmouseover=\"alert(\"'.$a.'\")\">LINK DESCRIPTION</a>';
```

Just simple like that ...